# Why Azure Yaml pipeline 'Template Parameter' if-condition does not resolve correctly while comparing the numbers?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have a `parent.yml` and `sub.yml` as shown here:

`parent.yml`:

```
variables:
  - name: JavaVersion
    value: 21

jobs:
  - template: templates/sub.yml
    parameters:
      JavaVersion: $(JavaVersion)
```

`sub.yml`:

```
parameters:
  JavaVersion: ''

jobs:
  - job: UseJavaVersion
    steps:
      - ${{ if ge(parameters.JavaVersion, 21) }}:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: Set default java version to ${{ parameters.JavaVersion }}

      - ${{ else }}:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: Install java version ${{ parameters.JavaVersion }}
```

When I run the job then it always goes to else part. Why 'if-condition' does not evaluates to true ? What am I doing wrong or missing here ?

I tried changing the variable value in the `parent.yml` to '21' and also in the `sub.yml` if-condition to '21', it did not work.

I also found some related discussions in this github page https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1749 but it did not really clarified my issue.

I expect that since variable JavaVersion has value 21 then if-condition in the `sub.yml` should be executed and we should see a step named as "Set default java version to ${{ parameters.JavaVersion }}".

Note: Since it always goes to else part the step display name shows the correct JavaVersion is resolved by the ${{ parameters.JavaVersion }}.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to perform a conditional insertion expression using a value that is only available at runtime.

Always remember: Variables are *evaluated at runtime*; Parameters *only exist at compile-time*.

If you want to do conditional-insertion at compile-time, you need to use a compile-time value for the parameter:

```yaml
# pipeline.yml
jobs:
  - template: templates/sub.yml
    parameters:
      JavaVersion: 21
```

If you want to use a variable, you'll have to use conditions on the tasks:

```yaml
# pipeline.yml
jobs:
- template: templates/sub.yml
  parameters:
    JavaVersion: $(currentJavaVersion)
```

```yaml
# templates/sub.yml
parameters:
- name: JavaVersion
  type: string

jobs:
- job: UseJavaVersion

  variables:
    javaVersion: ${{ parameters.JavaVersion }}
 
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Using Java 21 or greater
    condition: and( succeeded(), ge( variables['javaVersion'], 21) )
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: Write-Host "Using ${{ parameters.JavaVersion }}"

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Install java 
    condition: and( succeeded(), lt( variables['javaVersion'], 21) )
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: Write-Host "Installing!"
```

Comment: Thank you @bryanbcook, It resolved my issue but one thing I am still curious that I have defined a variable as isJava21: $[ge(variables['javaVersion'], 21)] and then printed the value of variable isJava21 in the script task and It always prints False. Since variables are resolved at runtime then isJava21 should print True. Have I understood it right?

Answer (score 0):

Just in addition to the previous answer, which is correct about the variables by default are only evaluated during runtime, however, by changing the syntax to `${{ variables.JavaVersion }}` we can get the variable(s) to be evaluated during compile-time:

```
variables:
  - name: JavaVersion
    value: 21

jobs:
  - template: templates/sub.yml
    parameters:
      JavaVersion: ${{ variables.JavaVersion }}
```

Using this approach you would not need to use `conditions` in each task as with the input into the `sub.yml` evaluated during compile-time, your pipeline if-statements should work as intended.